# How do I hide link by JavaScript ,

Tags: javascript

How do I hide link  by JavaScript ,

Then I restore assembled

Example: do I distribute the link inside the words and then I do that I may have to collect the original link

EX : 
first word = goo + glee - e = google
next word = c + o + m = com

link = first word +.+ next word 
= google.com

Comment: Once more, in English?

Comment: huh?? can try translating it into lamer term, coz its high :)

Comment: I guess you are trying to obfuscate name on the link? Right?

Comment: I'm sorry I newbie in learning English

yes, I am trying to obfuscate name on the link

Comment: Good Guy Dafny
But I want to hide it deeper this is very easy to identify him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing links on click can work like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function SetDest(a) {
                a.href = "http://stackoverflow.com" + "/questions/20782888/how-do-i-hide-link-by-javascript";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='' onclick='SetDest(this);'> Click Here </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But to obfuscate it, you would better use regex.  (still - it's possible to read, but little harder).

Comment: Good Guy Dafny
But I want to hide it deeper this is very easy to identify him

Comment: Well, This is the concept.  You can use base64, regex or simply google for "obfuscate strings with javascript".  I think that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458819/simplest-way-to-obfuscate-and-unobfuscate-a-string-in-javascript You may find very good explanation about this.