# How to disguise url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Let's say I have a URL as part of a webpage script like this:

```
<script>
var url = "http://www.example.com";
</script>
```

I don't want people to be able to read this URL easily. Obviously I realise that once it hits the client side they will be able to reverse engineer my code.

But I'm looking for a lightweight way to disguise this so that people can't just view/click it easily with view:source.

Comment: Maybe base64 (probably with a salt)

Comment: Well since javascript is a client side code, they will be able to read all of your javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to obfuscate and unobfuscate a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458819/simplest-way-to-obfuscate-and-unobfuscate-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Why do you want to hide this url? If for security you should take a look at server side code and not client side.

Answer (score 3):

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding), you can use base64:

```
// Encoding
var encoded = btoa(stringValue);

// Decoded
var decoded = atob(stringValue);
```

Easily decoded by anybody who knows how to access the browser console.

Comment: It will always be easy to decode since the question only want javascript answers, and javascript is a client code

Comment: @user1509104 Exactly right! I wouldn't recommend this for anything secure is what I'm basically saying

Comment: FWIW obfuscation is **NEVER** secure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

This is **NOT** secure, and i would **NOT** recommend this for anything security related.

But if you have to do it:

You can use a [javascript obfuscator](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx), which basically makes your code unreadable while it still works as i should.

Remember *unreadable* is not equal to *undecodable*.

It turns your javascript:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com";
```

Into:

```
var _0x5386=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x65\x78\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D"];var url=_0x5386[0]
```

Which is 100% the same code, just unreadable:

```
var _0x5386=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x65\x78\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D"];var url=_0x5386[0]

console.log(url); // http://www.example.com
```

Else take a look at Nick Bull's answer if you want to encode the url, but this will still leave your url readable for the naked eye if reading the javascript code.

This method does also have a weakness to the console window, since anyone could just type in the variable "url" and receive the url.

So all in all, this method will not leave your url in plaintext, but it does have the same console flaw like Nick Bull's answer.

But again, this is **NOT** secure.

Comment: It would be secure if you would proper JavaScript protection, javascript obfuscator is easily reversed. Have a look at jscrambler.com

Comment: Not sure why this answer was voted down. It is the only correct answer so far IMHO. It is super-lightweight compared to Jscrambler and makes the code not easily readable, just what the OP asked. Careful with base64 and other encodings, they are sometimes not supported by all browsers. But this is simple ASCII obfuscation, should work everywhere.

Comment: Is there any kind of alternative to obfuscation that is secure, but does the same kind of thing? Or is obfuscation inherently unsecure?

Answer (score 1):

[Jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com/en/) is the best option I have found if you want to conceal anything in your code. You can also add other layers of security to make reverse-engineering unfeasible and make the code detect debugging.

Comment: The question is not to protect the code or add a level of security, but to diguise a url inside the code by using a lightweight way to diguise the url in "View: Source"

Comment: exactly, conceal the url, thus my answer

Comment: By research Jscrambler did not seem like a "lightweight" way to disguise the url